# Is it possible to invoke a method based off a combobox.selecteditem.tostring() in C#?

Tags: c#, object, methods, invoke

Is it possible to invoke a method based of a text value?

I don't want to use 'if' or 'switch' statements if possible.

If so what do i need to look at to do this?

This is just to try and cleanup an interface.

Example with if statement:

```
    if (cmb_Motor.SelectedItem.ToString() == "OutPortA")
             NXT_Brick.OutPortA.SetOutputState();
    else if (cmb_Motor.SelectedItem.ToString() == "OutPortB")
             NXT_Brick.OutPortB.SetOutputState();
    else if (cmb_Motor.SelectedItem.ToString() == "OutPortC")
             NXT_Brick.OutPortC.SetOutputState();
```

I want to change the 'OutPortA,B,C' after 'NXT_Brick'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if` and `switch` statments could be hidded in a *dictionary*, for example:

```
private IDictionary<string, OutPort> ports = new Dictionary<string, OutPort>{
  {"OutPortA", NXT_Brick.OutPortA},
  {"OutPortB", NXT_Brick.OutPortB},
  {"OutPortC", NXT_Brick.OutPortC}
}
```

usage:

```
if(ports.Contains(key))
{
 ports[key].SetOutputState();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i did look at something to do with reflection to start with but i may have been heading down the wrong direction.

Answer (score 4):

The cleanest way I can think of would be to create a class for your combo box items like this:

```
class Item
{
  public string Name{get;set;}
  public Action Action{get;set;}

  public override string ToString() { return Name; }
}
```

Then you add instances of this class to your combo box:

```
cmbItems.Add(new Item{Name="Item1", Action=()=>{ /*action 1*/ });
cmbItems.Add(new Item{Name="Item2", Action=()=>{ /*action 2*/ });
cmbItems.Add(new Item{Name="Item3", Action=()=>{ /*action 3*/ });
```

And in your selected item changed event (or on your OK button press, wherever), you cast your `SelectedItem` property to `Item` and then call its `Action` property to run the code.

```
((Item)cmbItems.SelectedItem).Action();
```

Answer (score 1):

A combo box contains list items. Per MSDN, you can store ANYTHING in a combo box, though it's usually used to store text strings. So choose the simplest solution that solves the problem correctly.

```
public class FiringComboItem
{
   public string Text { get; set; }
   public Action OnClick { get; set; }
   override public ToString() { return Text; }
}
```

Add the items to the combo like this:

```
myCombo.Add ( new FiringComboItem 
    { 
        Text = "About", 
        OnClick = () => new AboutDialog.ShowDialog()
    });
```

In your dropdown handler:

```
private void myCombo_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (myCombo.SelectedItem As FiringComboItem).OnClick();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Delegates are pointers to functions/methods, so you might want to use that. For example, create an array of pointers to methods with the delegate signature (parameters and their types) and call the method by indexing the array. An example:

```
public delegate void SelectState();

public class Test
{
    SelectState[] stateMethods = new SelectState[]
    {
        new SelectState(SelectA),
        new SelectState(SelectC),
        new SelectState(SelectB),
        new SelectState(SelectB)
    };

    void SelectA() { /* ... */ }
    void SelectB() { /* ... */ }
    void SelectC() { /* ... */ }

    void DoSomething()
    {
        int index = cmb_Motor.SelectedIndex;
        // Get the method pointer.
        var method = stateMethods[index];
        // Call the method, one of the State*() methods.
        method();
    }
}
```

Or if you don't want to use an index but a string, as in your example, you might want to use a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, SelectState> stateMethods = new Dictionary<string, SelectState>
{
    {"OutPortA", new SelectState(SelectA)},
    {"OutPortB", new SelectState(SelectB)},
    {"OutPortC", new SelectState(SelectC)},
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A good solution (generally speaking - it might not be the best way in your special case, but to judge that, we'll need more information) seems like storing objects in the ComboBox rather than mere strings. These objects should provide the text visible in the ComboBox as well as a way to run the method you want to invoke.

In your example, it looks like you're always calling a `SetOutputState` method of an `OutPort` instance (assuming the class name here), so your ComboBox item objects could look like this:

```
public class ComboItem
{
    public ComboItem(string displayName, OutPort outPort)
    {
        this.displayName = displayName;
        this.outPort = outPort;
    }

    private readonly string displayName;

    private readonly OutPort outPort;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return displayName;
    }

    public OutPort OutPort {
        get {
            return outPort;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the result of the `ToString` method will be the string visible to the user in the ComboBox.

You would have to fill the ComboBox like this:

```
cmb_Motor.Items.Add(new ComboItem("OutPortA", NXT_Brick.OutPortA);
cmb_Motor.Items.Add(new ComboItem("OutPortB", NXT_Brick.OutPortB);
cmb_Motor.Items.Add(new ComboItem("OutPortC", NXT_Brick.OutPortC);
```

You can then evaluate the selected item like this:

```
ComboItem selectedItem = cmb_Motor.SelectedItem as ComboItem;
if (selectedItem != null) {
    selectedItem.OutPort.SetOutputState();
}
```

If you require more variation in what you want to do with the selected items, move the action to execute into the `ComboItem` class, too:

```
public class ComboItem
{
    public ComboItem(string displayName, OutPort outPort)
    {
        this.displayName = displayName;
        this.outPort = outPort;
    }

    private readonly string displayName;

    private readonly OutPort outPort;

    protected OutPort OutPort {
        get {
            return outPort;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return displayName;
    }

    public virtual void DoWork()
    {
        outPort.SetOutputState();
    }
}
```

The `OutPort` property is not required to be public any more now; you can simply call `DoWork` on the selected item. Hence, the evaluation code can be changed to this:

```
ComboItem selectedItem = cmb_Motor.SelectedItem as ComboItem;
if (selectedItem != null) {
    selectedItem.DoWork();
}
```

For anything that requires a different action, you can now derive a new class from `ComboItem` that overrides the `DoWork` method to do something different.